# How to use TensorFlow Dataset API in GANs training?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am training GANs model. For loading the dataset, I am using Dataset API of TensorFlow.

```
# train_dataset has image and label. z_train dataset has noise (z).
train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(train_file)
z_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.random_uniform([total_training_samples, seq_length,  z_dim],
                                                                 minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32))

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_dataset, z_train))
```

Creating Iterator:

```
iter = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes)
```

Using the iterator:

```
(img, label), z = iter.get_next()
train_init_op = iter.make_initializer(train_dataset)
```

While training the GAN in session:
Training Discriminator first:

```
_, disc_loss = sess.run([disc_optim, disc_loss])
```

then training Generator:

```
_, gen_loss = sess.run([gen_optim, gen_loss])
```

Here is the catch. Since, I am using **label** as condition (CGAN) in both, discriminator and generator graph, using two sess.run produces two different set of batch of **label** during the same run of batch.

```
for epoch in range(num_of_epochs):
    sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), train_init_op.initializer])
    for batch in range(num_of_batches):
        _, disc_loss = sess.run([disc_optim, disc_loss])
        _, gen_loss = sess.run([gen_optim, gen_loss])
```

Since, I have to feed the same batch of **label** in the generator's session run as in discriminator's session run, how shall I prevent Dataset API to produce two different batches in the same loop of a batch?

Note: I am using TensorFlow v1.9

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... can you just run all operations in the same session call? `sess.run([disc_optim, disc_loss, get_optim, gen_loss])`? Not sure I fully understand the question, but maybe check out how they do it in [GANEstimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/gan/estimator/GANEstimator). Also, any reason your `z_train` is part of the dataset and not just the output of `tf.random_uniform`?

Comment: before training Generator, I am checking if loss of discriminator is greater than 0.2 then only train discriminator. For this I need to run two different session calls.
I will check about GANEstimator as well. Thanks for your suggestion.
z_train dataset is actually tf.random_uniform embedded in the Dataset wrapper so that **img**, **label** and **z** can be extracted as a batch together without using the feed_dict

Comment: Pumping z through a dataset just leads to uneccessary data shipping from cpu to gpu. You can just have the dataset handle img, label and set z = tf.random... outside the dataset. You can also do conditional operations using `tf.cond` - something like `gen_optim = tf.cond(disc_loss < 0.2, lambda: gen_optim, tf.no_op)`. There might be some issues with `cond` expecting fn outputs to be the same shape/type, but that could be resolved using `tf.control_dependencies` or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 2 iterators for the same dataset. If you need to shuffle the dataset, you can even do that by specifying the seed as a tensor. See example below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

seed_ts = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,2,3,4,5]).shuffle(5, seed=seed_ts, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
it1 = ds.make_initializable_iterator()
it2 = ds.make_initializable_iterator()

input1 = it1.get_next()
input2 = it2.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for ep in range(10):
        sess.run(it1.initializer, feed_dict={seed_ts: ep})
        sess.run(it2.initializer, feed_dict={seed_ts: ep})

        print("Epoch" + str(ep))
        for i in range(5):
            x = sess.run(input1)
            y = sess.run(input2)
            print([x, y])
```